# List of day and next day in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, date, google-earth-engine-python-api

There is a list of days for a year. How can I convert it to another list in that each item includes two dates including the day and the next day?
I tried with the below code do it, but it is not correct!

```
Date_Start = ee.Date('2000-01-01')
Date_End = ee.Date('2000-12-31')
n_days = Date_End.difference(Date_Start,'day').round()
list_days = ee.List.sequence(1,n_days,1)

def make_datelist(n):
    day = Date_Start.advance(n,'day')
    next_day = Date_Start.advance(n - 1,'day')
    return [day, next_day]

dates = list_days.map(make_datelist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the correct classes for server-side approach (`ee.Number`):

```
Date_Start = ee.Date('2000-01-01')
Date_End = ee.Date('2000-12-31')
n_days = Date_End.difference(Date_Start,'day').round()
list_days = ee.List.sequence(1,n_days,1)

def make_datelist(n):
    day = Date_Start.advance(ee.Number(n),'day')
    next_day = Date_Start.advance(ee.Number(n).subtract(ee.Number(1)),'day')
    return ee.List([day, next_day])

dates = list_days.map(make_datelist)
```

Test:

```
dates.get(0).getInfo()
# [{'type': 'Date', 'value': 946771200000},
#  {'type': 'Date', 'value': 946684800000}]
```